# How do I see if another process is running on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a VC++ console app and I need to check to see if another process is running. I don't have the window title, all I have is the executable name. How do I get the process handle / PID for it? Can I enumerate the processes running with this .exe ?

Comment: This question is for VB, but the API calls should apply in C++ as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143301/how-to-enumerate-processes-from-vb-6-on-win-2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx) to enumerate the processes on a system.

You'll need to use OpenProcess to get a process handle, then [QueryFullProcessImageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the processes executable.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489(VS.85).aspx) Function

```
hSnapShot = FCreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
```

Followed by [Process32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834(VS.85).aspx) and [Process32Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684836(VS.85).aspx).

You will get a [PROCESSENTRY32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684839(VS.85).aspx) struct as follows with an szExeFile member.

```
PROCESSENTRY32W    processInfo;
processInfo.szExeFile
```

Make sure to first acquire the privilege `SeDebugPrivilege` before enumerating, that way you will get all processes across all sessions and users.

To acquire the privilege so you get all sessions:

```
acquirePrivilegeByName(SE_DEBUG_NAME);// SeDebugPrivilege
```

Where acquirePrivilegeByName is defined as:

```
BOOL acquirePrivilegeByName(
                            const TCHAR     *szPrivilegeName)
{
    HANDLE          htoken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES    tkp;
    DWORD           dwerr;

    //---------------- adjust process token privileges to grant privilege
    if (szPrivilegeName == NULL)
    {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, szPrivilegeName, &(tkp.Privileges[0].Luid)))
        return FALSE;

    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &htoken))
        return FALSE;

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, FALSE, &tkp, 0, NULL, NULL) ||
        GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)    // may equal ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED
    {
        dwerr = GetLastError();
        CloseHandle(htoken);
        SetLastError(dwerr);
        return FALSE;
    }

    CloseHandle(htoken);
    SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);

    return TRUE;
} //acquirePrivilegeByName()
```

If you need the full process image name you can use [QueryFullProcessImageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919(VS.85).aspx), but the szExeFile member may be enough for your needs.